# command not found: detox

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm, detox

I am trying to add detox e2e test to my project. I go through it's documentation, however, I can not install it on my machine.
This is my devDependencies:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.5",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.7",
    "@babel/preset-flow": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.7",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.4.5",
    "@testing-library/jest-native": "^3.4.3",
    "@testing-library/react-native": "^7.1.0",
    "@types/react-native-sqlite-storage": "^3.3.1",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.3",
    "babel-jest": "^24.8.0",
    "babel-plugin-add-module-exports": "^1.0.4",
    "babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node": "^2.3.3",
    "babel-plugin-transform-remove-console": "^6.9.4",
    "detox": "^17.14.3",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "jest-circus": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.54.1",
    "prettier": "^1.18.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.3"
  }
```

Also, I've `installed npm install -g detox-cli` , but I got `command not found: detox`

```
node : 10.22.1
os: Catalina
react-native: 0.61.2
```

Comment: Hmm. If `detox` is not found, something is broken with your PATH, I assume.

Comment: @LeoNatan How can I check about it? Because other commands are working(node, npm, react-native, and so on).

Comment: I’m not sure, I’m not really familiar with node/npm ecosystem, I just tolerate it enough to be able to work on Detox. Sorry. Try adding more tags to get the attention of node/npm experts here.

Comment: @LeoNatan Thanks for your helping :))) I added more tags

Comment: for mac : Try run command 'brew install detox'

Answer (score 0):

I hope that by now you already have figured out the answer but for the rest of the developers with the same problem my answer is the following

1st Make sure to install the detox CLI not only to add detox on your project, you can do it with: npm install -g detox-cli

2nd If you are using Expo CLI instead of the react-native cli that will be a problem because Expo support with Detox is entirely a community driven effort. We have no specific support in Detox for Expo applications.

If you are seeing an issue, it is most likely not an issue with Detox itself, but with the Expo runtime or with an incorrect Detox setup. For support on how to use Detox with Expo, you should contact the Expo team or the Expo community.

You can refer to [Expo github team and see this resolution](https://github.com/wix/Detox/blob/master/docs/Guide.Expo.md)